# start Apache from startup folder without user interaction

Tags: windows, apache-http-server

I have a simple .bat script that I placed in startup folder (`shell:startup`). I use autologon to logon to windows user account automatically. The scripts starts apache, curls that the computer is running and runs some other processes. It is executed, but apache never starts, namely because it needs to be run as admin.

This is the script

```
start /d "C:\Apache24\bin" httpd.exe && curl -d "computer=running" -X POST https://notify.me/path && someother stuff
```

Steps need to be executed in the same order as the script implies.

So how do I start apache from startup folder without user interaction?

I tried using a scheduled task, but even after correcting priorities to normal, the processes that I start runs extremely slow when executed as task. Like 15x slower than if I start them interactively.

The other thing that I tried is to create a shortcut, and checked "Run as administrator" and placed that shortcut in startup folder. This time the script was never executed.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't have Apache run as a service?

Comment: takes forever to start. also, I need to trigger curl after apache is running

Answer (score 0):

You can try/use hfs ( which is a single executable from rejetto - for windows )

this can be faster and better equipped to your need.